# Spring: are the EntityManager and Spring Repository not working in the same context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-entitymanager

I have two entities:

```
class Checkbook{
   ...
   private int canceledChecks;
   ...
}
```

and

```
class Check{
   ...
   @ManyToOne
   private Checkbook checkbook;

   private int status;
   ...
}
```

I want to increment the number of `canceledChecks` in the `Checkbook` entity whenever a `Check` has been canceled **`(status become 1)`**, so I created an event listener for this like so:

```
@Component
public class CheckChangeListener implements PreUpdateEventListener {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public boolean onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent event) {

        if(event.getEntity() instanceof Check){
            Check check = (Check)event.getEntity();
            CheckBook checkbook = check.getCheckBook();
            int oldStatus = getStatusFromEntityState(event.getOldState(), event);
            int newStatus = getStatusFromEntityState(event.getState(), event);

            if(oldStatus != newStatus && newStatus = 1){//means check is updated and canceled
                 checkbook.setCanceledChecks(checkbook.getCanceledChecks() + 1);
                 em.persist(checkbook); // persist new checkbook changes
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private int getStatusFromEntityState(Object[] state, PreUpdateEvent event){
        String[] properties = event.getPersister().getEntityMetamodel().getPropertyNames();
        int pos = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
            if(properties[i].equals("status")) pos = i;
        }

        return (Integer)state[pos];
    }
```

now in the `CheckController`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/check")
public class CheckController {

    @Autowired
    private CheckRepository repository;

    @PutMapping("/{id}/cancel")
    public ResponseEntity<Check> cancel(@PathVariable Long id) throws NotFoundException {
        Check check = repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("Check with id "+id+" not found!"));

        check.setStatus(1);

        repository.save(check);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED).body(check);
    }
}
```

Now the strange thing here is that the listener is being invoked but the checkbook is not updated.
**BUT**, when I change the controller like so:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/check")
public class CheckController {

    @Autowired
    private CheckRepository repository;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    @PutMapping("/{id}/cancel")
    public ResponseEntity<Check> cancel(@PathVariable Long id) throws NotFoundException {
        Check check = repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("Check with id "+id+" not found!"));

        check.setStatus(1);

        em.persist(check);
        em.flush();

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED).body(check);
    }
}
```

Now it works and the `Check` is being updated along with the `Checkbook` !!
I thought that `Spring data JPA` works in the same transaction as the `EntityManager`, am I right ?
I came from a `Symfony` background and we have only the `EntityManager` so the second scenario makes more sense to me (although I have to add the `@Transactional` annotation in order for it to work)
Why the second scenario works and the first does not ?!

Comment: @Kayaman when I called `check.getCheckbook()` it should be a managed entity right ?!

Comment: In the first scenario, are you sure the listener gets called **before** `CheckController.check` returns? I would normally expect the event to fire just before flushing, and the flushing would by default only occur when the transaction is being committed, which is soon **after** `CheckController.check` returns, but not necessarily **before** the response body gets serialized. This is precisely the kind of issues you get when you put transactions on controllers

Comment: @crizzis yes I've tested it and 100% sure it gets called before updating the entity in the database, hence the listener name `PreUpdateEventListener`, and I get both old and new state of the object `Check`. But it looks like spring, in the first scenario, does not use `EntityManager` to flush the entity in the database that's why the checkbook is not persisted because maybe the `EntityManager` I'm using in the listener and the one Spring using are not the same (just thinking not sure)

Comment: That wasn't my question. I wasn't asking *whether or not* it gets executed, but *when*. Did you debug your code, putting one breakpoint on `return ResponseEntity.status(...)` and another one inside the listener, and verified that the one inside the listener is indeed reached first?

Comment: @crizzis but I don't want the listener to be invoked after returning a response, I want to invoke it before running `repository.save(check)` !

Comment: That wasn't my question, either. I already have some idea how you *want* your code to work, you've already described it in sufficient detail. I'm asking *how your code is working now*

Comment: @crizzis ok I see what you mean now, to be honest I didn't put a breakpoint to check when it's being executed.